# Crash when replacing std::map value

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, struct, stdmap

I have this map

```
std::map<IPv4Address,std::vector<Agent>> report;
```

Where agent is defined as the following

```
typedef struct
{
    IPv4Address Address;
    AgentType Type;
    std::map <IPv4Address, IPRoute> RoutingTable;
    MetricType metric;
    int UpdateReceived = 0;
}Agent;
```

I am sending this Agent struct through `tcp sockets` and saving the values in the report `std::map`

```
int receive = recv(as.socket, (void *) &agent, sizeof(agent),0);
```

The routing table is initially empty. When the routing table size becomes >=1 the app crashes when adding to the map as seen below:

```
             mutex.lock();
             PrintInfo("Mutex locked");
             if(report.find(as.ip) != report.end())
             {
                 //f tells us if the agent was connected before to the router
                 bool f = false;
                 std::vector<Agent> tmpv =report[as.ip];
                 int tmp;

                 PrintInfo("Vector loop");
                 for(std::size_t i=0 ; i < tmpv.size() ; i++)
                 {
                     if(tmpv[i].Type == agent.Type)
                     {
                         f = true;
                         tmp = i;
                         break;
                     }
                 }

                 PrintInfo("Vector loop End");

                 if(f)
                 {
                     PrintInfo("Found -> Replacing");
  --> This line crashes  report[as.ip][tmp] = agent;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     PrintInfo("Not Found -> Adding");
                     report[as.ip].push_back(agent);
                 }


                 PrintInfo("After add");
             }
```

Comment: You can't send complex data that contains pointers over the network. Not even locally to another process of the same program. Pointers (like will be in a map) are local to the current process *only*. You need to [*serialize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the data structure.

Comment: " --> This line crashes" : What exactly is the crash ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'll try serializing and c what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After serializing the struct using `boost` library everything worked fine.

Here is an example of serialization :

Struct :

```
typedef struct
{
    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar,const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & Address & Type & InterceptionDuration & RoutingTable & metric & UpdateReceived;
    }

    IPv4Address Address;
    AgentType Type;
    double InterceptionDuration;
    std::map <IPv4Address, IPRoute> RoutingTable;
    MetricType metric;
    int UpdateReceived = 0;
}Agent;
```

Serializing :

```
std::string SerializeAgent(Agent a)
{
    std::ostringstream archive_stream;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive archive(archive_stream);
    archive << a;
    std::string s = archive_stream.str();
    return s;
}
```

Deserializing :

```
Agent DeserializeAgent(std::string s)
{
        Agent a;
        std::string r(&s[0],s.size());
        std::istringstream archive_stream(r);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive archive(archive_stream);
        archive >> a;
        return a;
}
```

Sending through socket :

```
std::string s = SerializeAgent(agent);
send(reporterSendingSocket,s.c_str(),s.size(),0);
```

Receiving through socket :

```
std::vector<char> response(REPORT_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

int receive = recv(as.socket, (void *) &response[0], response.size(),0);
```